# How to sort data from datagridview in descending in c#

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview

so i would like to fill my txtCourse and txtTimeslot into datagridview ,
then sort the txtTimeslot in descending and display txtCourse and txtTimeslot in datagridview

I have filled txtCourse and txtTimeslot into datagridview

```
string firstColum = txtCourse.Text;
string secondColum = txtTimeslot.Text;
string[] row = { firstColum, secondColum };

dgvLSD.Rows.Add(row);
```

I need to know how to sort the txtTimeslot in descending and display the txtCourse and txtTimeslot into datagridview

Comment: Set column's `SortMode` property to `Automatic`

Comment: it has already in Automatic mode